# Something related to a person not people in general

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the word or phrase for something related to one person *not* people in general. For example:

> This issue is very ???, it doesn't apply to other customers/people/users, so we skip it.

Comment: You could use broader terms such as 'restricted', 'rarely met [with]'. 'Idiosyncratic' is probably over-formal in this sense.

Comment: Or 'particular'? 'specific'? 'discrete'? By the way, your first comma needs to be a colon. Your sentence might be re-worded: "This issue is a very <particular> one: it doesn't apply to other customers..." That's clearer I think.

Comment: Instead of using a word with an inclusive context like idiosyncratic, I'd suggest using a phrase with an exclusive context such as "not pervasive". Example: "This issue is not very pervasive, so I suggest we skip it." Or rephrase entirely: "This issue affects only one customer within our entire customer base, so I suggest we skip it."

Comment: Consider *narrow*.

Comment: This is a personal issue. This is an issue affecting/related to the individual.

Comment: "This issue is **specific**, it doesn't apply to other customers/people." (I would avoid "**very** specific" as "specific" is probably ungradeable.)

Comment: All good suggestions but I would actually say *localized*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simply way too many options, here are a few based on your context:

***Specific***

> connected with one particular thing only

***Personal***

> not belonging to or connected with anyone else

***Individual***

> connected with one person; designed for one person

***Peculiar***

> strange or unusual, especially in a way that is unpleasant or makes you worried

***Eccentric***

> considered by other people to be strange or unusual

***Rare***

> not done, seen, happening, etc. very often

***Singular***

> connected with or having the singular form

***Uncommon***

> ​not existing in large numbers or in many places

Or, if you want to be more precise, you can use compound words to describe exactly what's causing the problem for this one person:

> This issue is very ***device-specific***, so let's skip it.
>
> This issue is very ***location-specific***, so let's skip it.

(Oxford)

Comment: 'Oxford' could refer to many dictionaries.